# How to get GETDATE() from multiple linked Servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have around 10 Linked Servers, i need to get GETDATE() datetime from each of these Linked Server and store it in a table. Please help me out to how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into table
(all_Dates)
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(USLinkedServer, 'SELECT getdate()')
union
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(UKLinkedServer, 'SELECT getdate()')
union
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(AUSLinkedServer, 'SELECT getdate()')
.
.
.
```

Remember, OPENQUERY requires that the linked server is already set up

Answer (score 1):

You can use **OPENQUERY** to get the result set from **remote server** which are added as **linked server**.

The syntax is **OPENQUERY ( linked_server ,'query' )**

Any user can execute **OPENQUERY**. The permissions that are used to connect to the remote server are obtained from the settings defined for the linked server.

```
INSERT INTO table (DateColumn)
SELECT Date
FROM OPENQUERY(RemoteServerName1, 'SELECT GETDATE() AS Date')
UNION ALL
SELECT Date
FROM OPENQUERY(RemoteServerName2, 'SELECT GETDATE() AS Date')
UNION ALL
SELECT Date
FROM OPENQUERY(RemoteServerName3, 'SELECT GETDATE() AS Date')
```

Answer (score 0):

OPENQUERY can be used if that server is added in linked server list using sp_addLinkServer and accessible column should be 1. as per my understanding.